# Not sure why this is true about matrices, but this isn't if they are commutative

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three matrices.

Although for general matrices $PQ \ne QP$, in this particular case I am told that $AC=CA$.

I am also told that $A(B+C) \ne BA + CA$.

If I am being told in part of the question that the matrices are commutative when being multiplied (as in $AC = CA$), why isn't $A(B+C) = BA + CA$?

Comment: Why do you say that AC=CA?  Matrix multiplication is most emphatically _not_ commutative.

Comment: (Also, A(B+C) = AB+AC; from the terms you've described, presumably you mean to write (A+B)C?)

Comment: I think you mean $BA=CA$. (But I also think you're confused on a deeper level than that.)

Comment: No, I meant AC = CA. Everything I wrote is how the problem describes it.

Comment: Okay, so I now have two answers basically flipping everything. So apparently AC = CA is not true and A(B+C) = BC + CA is true...

Comment: A(B+C)=BC+CA is not true. Maybe you're thinking of A(B+C)=AB+AC

Comment: A(B+C)=BC+CA isn't even true for integers; try taking, e.g., A=2, B=3, C=4. 2(3+4) = 14 <> 20 = 3.4+4.2

Comment: Please note that the equation is not A(B+C)=BC+CA, its BA+CA

Answer (score 6):

You are given that $AC = CA$ i.e. *that $A$ and $C$ commmute*. You are not told that $A$ commutes with *every* matrix. Therefore, we cannot conclude that $A(B+C) = BA + CA$. In fact, the claim that $A(B+C) \ne BA + CA$ is perfectly consistent with the given data. Indeed, distributivity gives $$A(B+C) = AB + AC$$
and then commutativity of $A$ and $C$ gives $$A(B+C) = AB + CA.$$
Since matrix addition is invertible, the inequality $AB + CA \ne BA + CA$ is equivalent to $AB \ne BA$ (just subtract $CA$ from both sides). Thus, *$A$ and $B$ do not commute*. This is fine. It is very easy to find three matrices that act like this: take two matrices that don't commute, and let $C = I$ be the identity matrix.